# Parsing File name of a doc file of java

Tags: java, string-parsing

I want to parse the file names of multiple doc files (MS office) using java.
How should I go about doing this?

I was able to find an API on extracting info from the doc itself, but I can't
find information on the file name itself.

So say I have a doc file `XX_232312_22`, I want to just parse the file name (ie `232312` part).

EDIT: What would we do if we need to parse more than just one file?
For instance, all 1000 files in one directory?

Comment: Are you looking for `new File("path/file.doc").getName()`?

Comment: So you mean you want to `angelsoft2311` out of `angelsoft2311-1`? Am I right? OR do you have anymore issues in getting file name.

Comment: `file.getName().replaceFirst("\\.\\w+$", "");`

Comment: Actually file names are like this XX_232121_00 . So I want to extract 232121 from the file name.

Comment: Do you have the filenames or just the directory names?  Btw, if you have more than one question to ask, you should post separate questions.

Comment: Alright. Just filenames in a directory. I will post a separate question!

Comment: If this question has been answered, then it is customary to mark an answer.

Comment: However, a more interesting problem is to extract metadata from the document. if you need the author, or the title, or the creation date, you'll need a metadata extraction tool, and perhaps software like Apache POI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] parts = filename.split("-");
parts[0] // part before dash
parts[1] // part after dash
```

You can look up String.split in the java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

EDIT:

OP changed the format of the filename to XX_filename__00.

It would then be

```
String[] parts = filename.split("_");
parts[0] // part before first _
parts[1] // part between two _
parts[2] // part after second _
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

`fileName.split("-")[0]`